# Equivalent to the SQL limit function in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am using this tutorial to learn how to paginate a results set. The thing is, the tutorial is grabbing results from a SQL db.

I am working with results from an XML file.

SO my Question is: is there a function in PHP that is the equivalent to the SQL LIMIT function the tutorial is using? and how would I go about changing the below code?

First off the tutorial uses these lines to get the total results:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM testimonials WHERE approved='1'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query); 
// Here we have the total row count 
$rows = $row[0];
```

I am using this line instead

```
$total_results = $xml->rs->tr;

// This is the total number of results we want to allow per page
$results_per_page = 20;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($total_results/$results_per_page);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Establish the $pagnum variable
$pagenum = 1;
// Get pagenum from url if it is present
if(isset($_GET['pn'])) {
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
// This makes sure the page numner isn't below 1
if ($pagenum <1) {
    $pagenum = 1;
} elseif ($pagenum > $last {
    $pagenum = $last;
}
```

This is where I get confused. How would i change the below code to work with my xml results?

```
// This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum 
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $results_per_page .',' .$results_per_page; 

// This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, datemade FROM testimonials 
WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC $limit"; $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL LIMIT in PHP is just a call to the function `array_slice()`. Example:

```
// Assuming your data is contained in an array $array

$array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$slice = array_slice($array,3,4);
print_r($slice);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
)
```

Working example: http://codepad.org/sGcyPimT
You can control the LIMIT and the OFFSET of SQL with `int $offset` and `$int length` arguments of [array_slice](https://www.php.net/array_Slice).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what XML lib you're using, if it returns simple array you could use `array_slice()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php, if you use some custom XML library, there should be method which helps you to do something like this. Try to display all available methods with: `get_class_methods($xml)`